# Xamarin - how to center controls using the IDE , visually?

Tags: xamarin-studio

I have a splashscreen / launchscreen. It contains a title (label), an image 300x300 and a small label that says copywrite info. I'm trying to center the 3 controls vertically so they fill the screen. (at least look nice) I can't figure out or find instructions how to center the 3.  I can create vertical constraints, width contraints and constraints relative to the other controls. But they never appear centered on iPhone5, iPhone6, 6plus etc...

how do you center 3 controls vertically and horizontally using the IDE, so they appear correctly on ALL devices/layouts?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do you center 3 controls vertically and horizontally using the IDE, so they appear correctly on ALL devices/layouts?

Its strange that Xamarin Studio doesn't have a quick auto layout toolbar similar to XCode where you can align your controls vertically or horizontally with one click.

But they provide one not so obvious way to do it. 
1. Make sure when you place any control on any screen on storyboard, you place it vertical center with the help of guiding lines.
2. Once you place it click on the control again when it shows the constraint guidelines.
3. At the center of the control there is a dot, drag that dot to until you see the vertical guideline and place it once the line turns blue.

Now your control should be aligned vertically center for all devices.

Hope this helps, happy coding :)